# Changing the integration limits takes a long time to evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[image: Mathematica session]

```
Integrate[x*Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x]^2), {x, 0, π}]
```

> `π^2/4`

But

```
Integrate[x*Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x]^2), {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

takes much more time to do.

Why?

Comment: Some folks here prefer the quoted environment (`> output`) for output. (I don't because it doesn't format properly is less readable.) Others prefer quoted-code (``> `output` ``), which is how I altered it, because it formats correctly; some dislike the two-tone formatting. (I prefer commented code, `(* output *)`, because I can copy the input and output, and switch to *M* to run it without editing, and I have the output to compare with there in *M*.  But some seem to prefer the look of the other styles over the functionality of this one.) To each their own.

Comment: On the computer I am borrowing, versions 8, 10, and 11 are able to evaluate both integrals, but the second takes about five times as long as the first in version 8, about eight times as long in version 10, and about 35 times as long in version 11. Make of it what you will. (Additionally, only version 10 produced the simple answer.)

Comment: @J.M. In the first case `Integrate` uses by-parts to get an integral in terms of `ArcTan[Cos[x]]`, which is 1-1 over `{x, 0, Pi}` but not over `{x, 0, 2 Pi}`. I can't tell if that's the reason or not that a different approach is used. Nonetheless more extensive checking is done in the second case.

Comment: With v12 on my Mac, the second integral took **68** times as long.

Comment: I suspect branch cut checking has gotten more extensive and careful over time.

Comment: `Integrate[x*Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x]^2), {x, Pi, 2 Pi}]` is slow, too. So my 1-1 comment is probably not relevant. `Integrate[x*Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x]^2), {x, -Pi, 0}]` is fast, and the integral over `{x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}` is medium-slow, about half the time as over `{x, Pi, 2 Pi}`. I'm thinking at this point it's not worth going much deeper into why....

Comment: This one, which differs by the fast one by a scalar multiple, is nearly as slow as the OP's slow one: `Integrate[-2 x*Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x]^2), {x, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties lol your edit comment "so many o's you forgot the n".  But for the sake of future search, shouldn't it be edited to just "long"?

Comment: @QuantumDot, will edit later; just leaving it up for a while for fun ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose that discontinuity of the antiderivative at $3/2\pi$ and $5/2\pi$ is the reason.
[image]

It is interesting to notice that the raw answer to the second integral is enormous, but `FullSimplify` reduces it to 
$$-\frac{\pi^2}{2}$$

Comment: Oh hey I get to link to one of my favorite blog posts:  [Mathematica and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Very nice blog indeed!